# PHP - Problemas para mostrar un valor de un Select con mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

tengo un problema relativamente sencillo pero me ha dado un par de dolores de cabeza, resulta que tengo el siguiente código:

```html
$id_curso=$_POST["curso"];
 
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'capacitaciones');
$nombre_curso=("SELECT `nombre_curso` FROM `capacitaciones`.`cursos` WHERE `id_curso`='$id_curso'");
$curso=mysqli_query($con, $nombre_curso);
```

Con esto, capturo el valor del ID curso del formulario (ej: 1) y lo comparo con la tabla "cursos" de la BD "capacitaciones", esto con el fin de obtener el nombre del curso que se encuentra en la tabla,

El problema esta en que al compilar el código me aparece el siguiente error:

Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\capacitacion\encuestas\enviado.php on line 71

¿Como puedo capturar el resultado de la query SELECT y guardarlo en una variable para mostrarlo en un echo?

Ej: echo "Nombre del curso: ",$curso

Muchas gracias por cualquier ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido a Stackoverflow.

Estás declarando mal la consulta, no deberías usar paréntesis.

Prueba el código así:

```
$id_curso=$_POST["curso"];

$con=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'capacitaciones');
$sql="SELECT `nombre_curso` FROM `capacitaciones`.`cursos` WHERE `id_curso`='$id_curso'";

if ( $curso=mysqli_query($con, $sql) ) {
    while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($curso)) {
        echo $obj->nombre_curso.PHP_EOL;
    }
    /* liberar el conjunto de resultados */
    mysqli_free_result($curso);
} else {
    echo "Error: ". mysqli_error($con);
}

/* cerrar la conexión */
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado, saludos